# Uniformly Approximating Lipschitz functions by Polynomial Functions

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f\in\operatorname{Lip}_K[a,b]$, show that $f$ can be uniformly approximated  by polynomials in $\operatorname{Lip}_K[a,b]$.

Attempt:

$\operatorname{Lip}_K[a,b]$ is collection of all real valued Lipschitz functions on $[a,b]$, with constant at most $K$. So if $f$ is any Lipschitz function on that interval, then we can say that $f$ can be approximated uniformly by a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)$, so we are saying that  $\forall \epsilon >0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\geq N\implies||f-p_n||_{\infty}<\epsilon$.

$\operatorname{Lip}_K[a,b]$ is a subspace of $C([a,b])$ and actually since $[a,b]$ is compact, we go further and say that $\operatorname{Lip}_K[a,b]$ is a subalgebra of $C([a,b]).$ $\operatorname{Lip}_K[a,b]$ definitely vanishes at no point (since constant functions are Lipschitz). I'm having difficulties showing that they separate points though. Assuming that I've somehow shown that it does separate points, then Stone-Weierstrass can be applied, and hence $\operatorname{Lip}_K[a,b]$ is dense in $C([a,b])$

Or something along those lines... I don't think what I have is quite right since I'm not making enough reference to the actual function $f$, and also showing that the space is dense in the other space doesn't mean that $||f-p_n||_{\infty}<\epsilon$

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: $\text{Lip}_K[a, b]$ is not an algebra: $x\in \text{Lip}_1[0,1]$ but $x^2$ isn't.

Comment: @Mikael, perhaps you meant $\operatorname{Lip}(X)$ is a subalgebra of $C(X)$, where $X$ is compact?